# How to optimize SELECT against a constant value?

Tags: mysql, indexing, where-clause

Because I am using a data structure beyond my control, there is a table in my DB which will potentially have millions of `Foreign-key => (key => value)` pairs. Now, I know that one of the keys will be a certain value (in this case the key is `related_content`). Is it possible for MySQL to optimize the query so that it does not have to search the entire table for results?

Example table (called `meta`):

```
fk | key               | value
====================================
1  | 'related_content' | '[2,3,4]'
1  | 'condiment'       | 'mayo'
1  | 'condiment'       | 'bananas'
29 | 'condiment'       | 'ketchup'
29 | 'related_content' | '[1,7,9]'
95 | 'condiment'       | 'mustard'
95 | 'related_content' | '[5,6,8]'
```

Example query:

```
SELECT value FROM meta WHERE fk = 29 AND key = 'related_content';
```

What I would like to do is:

```
ALTER TABLE `meta` ADD INDEX `meta_related` ON (`key`) WHERE `key` = 'related_content';
```

(Before anyone asks, the `key` column already has an index on it)

Comment: If you already have a key on `key` why do you think another one would be of some help? And why do you need it - is it slow?

Comment: Since the set of content where `key = related_content` dramatically smaller than the complete content, then it seems like having a specialized, separate index would be faster.

Comment: If the key is used it should be super fast and probably can't be speed up any more. No idea if changing the key to `desc` order would benefit anything - I doubt it.

Comment: As to "is it slow" the answer is "no... for now". This is a value which will need to be queried before another join can be attempted. (Basically, this table is storing *user* content and we need to determine whether an automated process needs to be used. Because of how data is serialized, we need to return the results of the initial query to the client language before creating a new query. Anything we can do to optimize that time would be best).

Comment: Is the reason here that you are doing allot of operations on the sub-set that matches related_content? Possibly you could start by building a temp table that contains only the related_content rows? Once that initial select is done you have the correct set ready for all other operations.

Comment: I'm also curious. While I haven't seen anything which has said that this is possible, it seems like there would be something that could be implemented without excess of hassle.

Comment: I don't know any method to implement conditional indexes in MySQL.

Comment: @Giles I'd like to avoid a temp. table if possible (unless it is transparent to the client language), though that isn't a terrible idea.

Comment: @juergend Neither do I. :-)

Comment: If the queries start getting slow you could think about [*Partitioning*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-overview.html).

Comment: I honestly think you would be pressed to notice much performance increase over the current index even if you could create such an index.

Comment: what if you will add the key_index (int11) column  that will represent the string  in a key column like : related_content =1, condiment=2 and you will add index on key_index column, the index on int will be faster than on string, at the end you will select using two indexed integer field. It's gonna be fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 'composite' index

```
 INDEX(fk, key)
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you will add the key_index (int11) column that will represent the string in a key column like : related_content =1, condiment=2 and you will add index on key_index column, the index on int will be faster than on string, at the end you will select using two indexed integer field. It's gonna be fast